# Here API -'routing mode’ unexpected result

Tags: here-api

I have a question about the result of the routing api according the ‘routing mode’.

**Routing mode Fast**
I use the following request with the “routingMode=fast” option. I expect a result that is optimized for the travel time (duration).

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&departureTime=any&return=summary&origin=50.90089918068732,5.916744771297889&destination=50.91922009774642,6.024552765189207&routingMode=fast&apiKey=

The result summary is:

```json
"summary":{"duration":1031,"length":11170,"baseDuration":1031}
```

**Routing mode Short**
Then I use the same request, but with “routingMode=short”. I expect a result that is optimized for the travel length.

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&departureTime=any&return=summary&origin=50.90089918068732,5.916744771297889&destination=50.91922009774642,6.024552765189207&routingMode=short&apiKey=

The result summary is:

```json
"summary":{"duration":1098,"length":10725,"baseDuration":1098}
```

This route is shorter than the first request, so far so good.

**Routing mode Fast with alternative routes**
However, now I back to the “routingMode=fast” and add the option for alternatives to the request (alternatives=1).

https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&departureTime=any&return=summary&alternatives=1&origin=50.90089918068732,5.916744771297889&destination=50.91922009774642,6.024552765189207&routingMode=fast&apiKey=

The response contains two routes as a result. The first is:

```json
"summary":{"duration":1031,"length":11170,"baseDuration":1031}
```

(same as the request without alternatives)

The second is:

```json
"summary":{"duration":966,"length":17028,"baseDuration":966}
```

The duration of the alternative route is 966 minutes, this is less than the original 1031 minutes. This alternative is the fastest route. Why isn’t this the response on the request without alternatives? I would expect that since I use “routingMode=fast” I always receive the fastest route as a first result. Can anyone explain this? I cannot find this in the documentation of the api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We changed the name from fastest to fast, since we consider other things along side travel time. Certain situations add penalties which do not show in the ETA. In this case the fastest route goes bit more through FRC5 roads, which are slightly penalized. Plus it uses few slip roads, which also have a penalty on them.